# Is there a way to check if a var is using setInterval()?

Tags: javascript

For instance, I am setting an interval like

```
timer = setInterval(fncName, 1000);
```

and if i go and do

```
clearInterval(timer);
```

it does clear the interval but is there a way to check that it cleared the interval? I've tried getting the value of it while it has an interval and when it doesn't but they both just seem to be numbers.

Comment: it does work (clearing it) - so I'm not sure why you need to inspect it?

Comment: id just like to know if there is an interval waiting at any specific time.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

There is no direct way to do what you are looking for. Instead, you could set `timer` to false every time you call `clearInterval`:

```
// Start timer
var timer = setInterval(fncName, 1000);

// End timer
clearInterval(timer);
timer = false;
```

Now, `timer` will either be false or have a value at a given time, so you can simply check with

```
if (timer)
    ...
```

If you want to encapsulate this in a class:

```
function Interval(fn, time) {
    var timer = false;
    this.start = function () {
        if (!this.isRunning())
            timer = setInterval(fn, time);
    };
    this.stop = function () {
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = false;
    };
    this.isRunning = function () {
        return timer !== false;
    };
}

var i = new Interval(fncName, 1000);
i.start();

if (i.isRunning())
    // ...

i.stop();
```

Comment: this is what i planned to do if no was the answer to my question. i wrote something similar:
`var stopInterval = function(varname) {
      clearInterval();
      varname = false;
    }

    var isRunning = function(varname) {
      return !!varname;
    }`
i know this exactly wont work because varname will probably be a string, thus making it always true, but its the idea that works for me. your way would work as well but people beware that setInterval() gives the var a numeric value and if it could come out as 1 or 0 meaning t/f.

Comment: eh, i guess formatting doesnt work in comments... my bad. does anyone know how to format code in a comment or is that just not allowed at all?

Comment: Use `if (timer !== false)` to avoid the numeric problem. (Count the equal signs)

Comment: @yankee I want to be able to start a timer only if it has been cleared and is not running anymore, if(!timer) works great but I can't get the same result with if(timer != true) or if(timer !== true)

Comment: @baptx: In the code by Casey it says `timer = false;`. Did you do that?

Comment: @yankee yes and that's why I can check now with if(!timer), but if(timer != true) and if(timer !== true) doesn't fit conditions I don't understand, you can find an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/RHeZN/11/

Comment: @baptx You need `if (timer === false)`. That's because `setInterval` returns a numeric value, which does not strictly equal `true`. Also, I added some code that encapsulates the logic that you can use.

Comment: @baptx:  Well yes, the way you are looking at things you need to check if timer is a boolean false (like Casey Chu says). That is not the same as checking whether it is not a boolean true `(timer === false) != (timer !== true)`. I changed your code: http://jsfiddle.net/RHeZN/12/ Now it's more failsafe.

Comment: @yankee thanks, it's working now but I've found a much simpler and cleaner solution, just call the stop function at the beginning of the start function and it's ok. For my case this is the way to go because I have a counter that I want to reset to a specified number of seconds as argument, even if it's running. This way, I'm sure the value will be displayed after the full setInterval pause (1000ms), and not the time remaining from setInterval (I don't know if you really understand :p)

Comment: Or instead of setting `timer` to false, you can do `delete timer;`

Answer (score 10):

The return values from `setTimeout` and `setInterval` are completely opaque values. You can't derive any meaning from them; the only use for them is to pass back to `clearTimeout` and `clearInterval`.

There is no function to test whether a value corresponds to an active timeout/interval, sorry! If you wanted a timer whose status you could check, you'd have to create your own wrapper functions that remembered what the set/clear state was.

Answer (score 2):

I did this like below, My problem was solved. you should set the value like "false", when you clearTimeout the timer.

```
var timeer=false;
----
----
if(timeer==false)
{
  starttimer();  
}
-----
-----
function starttimer()
{
  timeer_main=setInterval(activefunction, 1000);
  timeer=true;
}

function pausetimer()
{
  clearTimeout(timeer_main);
  timeer=false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well you can do

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {}, 1000);
interval = clearInterval(interval);
if (typeof interval === 'undefined'){
...
}
```

but what are you actually trying to do? clearInterval function is an always success function and it will always return undefined even if you call it with a NaN value, no error checking in there.

Answer (score 1):

You COULD override the setInterval method and add the capability to keep track of your intervals. Here is an untestet example to outline the idea. It will work on the current window only (if you have multiple, you could change this with the help of the prototype object) and this will only work if you override the functions BEFORE any functions that you care of keeping track about are registered:

```
var oldSetInterval = window.setInterval;
var oldClearInterval = window.clearInterval;
window.setInterval = function(func, time)
{
  var id = oldSetInterval(func, time);
  window.intervals.push(id);
  return id;
}
window.intervals = [];
window.clearInterval = function(id)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < window.setInterval.intervals; ++i)
    if (window.setInterval.intervals[i] == id)
    {
      window.setInterval.intervals.splice(i, 1);
    }
  oldClearInterval(id);
}
window.isIntervalRegistered(id)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < window.setInterval.intervals; ++i)
    if (window.setInterval.intervals[i] == func)
      return true;
  return false;
}



var i = 0;
var refreshLoop = setInterval(function(){
    i++;
}, 250);

if (isIntervalRegistered(refrshLoop)) alert('still registered');
else alert('not registered');
clearInterval(refreshLoop);
if (isIntervalRegistered(refrshLoop)) alert('still registered');
else alert('not registered');
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem: Create a global counter that is incremented within your code performed by setInterval. Then before you recall setInterval, test if the counter is STILL incrementing. If so, your setInterval is still active. If not, you're good to go.