# if setInterval is cleared?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to check if a var is using setInterval() ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679141/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-var-is-using-setinterval)

how can I check if a setInterval is cleared?

```
var i = 0;
var refreshLoop = setInterval(function(){
    i++;
}, 250);

clearInterval(refreshLoop);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless it is deleted, your refreshLoop variable will return an integer before or after it is cleared.