# How can I detect if an object is an interval/timeout?

Tags: javascript, node.js

For **node.js**

```
var timer = setInterval(function(){console.log('hi')},1000);
var notATimer = {};
var number = 2;

detectTimer(timer) //returns true
detectTimer(notATimer) //returns false
detectTimer(number) //returns false
```

Is there any way to reliably determine whether or not an object is an interval?
Also, bonus points if the way to detect it also works for setTimeout.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: `typeof timer` is `number` and `notATimer` is an `object`.

Comment: @Nonemoticoner that won't suffice a generic setup. An edit was made though to explicitly mention that.

Comment: @Nonemoticoner: `typeof timer`  is `"object"` in node

Comment: @Bergi Is it? Sorry then. I'm using FF console atm.

Comment: If you are detecting within your own architecture, maybe explicitly define your own type.
https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2011/11/04/custom-types-classes-using-object-literals-in-javascript/

Comment: I'm not aware of anyway to do it - but one hack-ish way, add a property to setTimeout prototype `prototype.someProp = 'timer'` and then check for that, or better yet defer to @Neals answer

Comment: _Sort of_ duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679141/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-var-is-using-setinterval

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In nodejs, [`setTimeout`](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_settimeout_callback_delay_arg) and [`setInterval`](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setinterval_callback_delay_arg) return [`Timeout`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/timers.js#L442-L450) instances. That constructor is not exported, but you still can access it and use it to detect timer objects:

```
const Timeout = setTimeout(function(){}, 0).constructor;
function isTimer(t) { return t instanceof Timeout; }
```

If you don't want to do that, you can also use duck typing, by testing what properties the object has.

Comment: My answer will work both on the node end and on the client end.

Comment: Also accessing the constructor of an object is "icky" in my opinion.

Comment: @Neal: Sure, a wrapper will be necessary for the client side (and is a good solution!), but that's not what the OP asked for. It's also true that there are good reasons why `Timeout` is not exported, and working around those can possibly bring you in trouble, but it's the only really reliable way.

Comment: on node v11.5.0 that doesn't work: "ReferenceError: Timeout is not defined"

Comment: @ekkis Hm, I can't try it right now, can you inspect the return value of `setTimeout` with a debugger please?

Answer (score 9):

Both `setTimeout` and `setInterval` return an id reference (in the browser).

In node they return a reference to a `Timeout` object.

So **no**, there is no real way to determine whether the returned value is from a timer, or just a variable from somewhere in the browser.

In **node** you can *technically* do an `instanceof Timeout` check on the returned value's constructor, but personally I do not like doing that.

---

You *can* however wrap your timer implementation in some wrapping object caller which you can then check for which will work on node *and* on the client side.

For example:

```
class Timer {
    constructor(callback, time) {
         this.timeId = setTimeout(callback, time);
    }
    clear() {
         clearTimeout(this.timeId);
    }
}

const time = new Timer(() => console.log('hi'), 1000);

console.log(time instanceof Timer); // true
```

Comment: This question is about node, not the DOM api.

Comment: @Bergi I am not sure where I said anything about the DOM api in my answer.

Comment: The answer's first paragraph implies that, because Node doesn't return an integer reference for timers.

Comment: @Neal: You expected the DOM api to be used, as you said that the functions are returning numbers.

Comment: What does `setInterval` have to do with the DOM API? `setInterval` returns an `number`, which is the id used when cancelling via `clearInterval()`

Comment: Thats what I said lux ... @bergi did not seem to agree

Comment: @Bergi I'm very confused about your obsession with the DOM in this answer; there's no DOM in this.

Comment: The DOM API returns an integer, identifying the timer. The CommonJS API (same call) returns a Timer object. This is the right solution *if* you're running in a browser.

Comment: @ndugger: Sorry for my sloppy formulation. It should've been "*This question is about code executed in a node JS environment, not a DOM environment with the [HTML5 Timer API](https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/timers.html)*". While a wrapper object can be a good solution to the problem the OP is facing, imo this answer ("*no*") doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @Bergi updated my answer... Did not know all of this nodejs info.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible with regular methods as already mentioned by others. However, you could create a wrapper like

```
// Timeout, Interval, whatever
class Interval {
    constructor(...args) {
        this.interval = setInterval(...args); // again, whatever fits your needs
        return this;
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

Which, applied, would be

```
const timer = new Interval(() => console.log('I am an interval'), 1000);

console.log(timer instanceof Interval) // => true (It's an interval)
```

Now that's just a basic example but I hope it gives you the right idea.

Comment: Copy/paste much? ;-P Looks good to me, however it is the same what is in my answer.

Comment: Yeah I just noticed as well, but I assure you that I did not copy you :P

Comment: I was so happy that I could finally give an answer on SO, but there was you ^^

Comment: Happy to help ... I think?

Comment: @Neal Exactly :)

Answer (score -3):

I would suggest changing the setTimeout and setInterval functions for javascript, I realized after the fact that you tagged this for node.js as well, so here's a javascript answer only,  as the other answers handle node.js very well

```js
window.originalSetTimeout=window.setTimeout;
window.originalClearTimeout=window.clearTimeout;
window.originalSetInterval=window.setInterval;
window.originalClearInterval=window.clearInterval;



window.setTimeout=function(func,delay)
{

    ret=window.originalSetTimeout(func,delay);
    ret +='-timeout';
    return ret;
};
window.setInterval=function(func,delay)
{

    ret=window.originalSetInterval(func,delay);
    ret +='-interval';
    return ret;
};

window.clearTimeout=function(timerID)
{
    tid=timerID.split('-')[0];
    window.originalClearTimeout(tid);
};
window.clearInterval=function(timerID)
{
    tid=timerID.split('-')[0];
    window.originalClearInterval(tid);
};

isTimeout=function(timerID)
{
    t=timerID.split('-')[1];
    if(t == "timeout") return true;
     return false;
}
isInterval=function(timerID)
{
    t=timerID.split('-')[1];
    if(t == "interval") return true;
     return false;
}  

t=setTimeout(function(){console.log('here');},5000);

if(isTimeout(t)) document.getElementById('mess').innerHTML+='<BR>t is a Timeout';
if(isInterval(t)) document.getElementById('mess').innerHTML+='<BR>t is an Interval';

p=setInterval(function(){console.log('Interval here');},5000);
if(isTimeout(p)) document.getElementById('mess').innerHTML+='<BR>p is a Timeout';
if(isInterval(p)) document.getElementById('mess').innerHTML+='<BR>p is an Interval';
```

```html
<div id="mess"></div>
```

.

Comment: There is no `window` in nodejs

Comment: didn't realize this was for node.

Comment: @GregBorbonus It was barely clear. Not mentioned explicitly in the question, only indirectly via tagging, which is often spammed and unreliable.

Comment: Thanks lux, I edited the answer to show it was a mistake. I've never even thought of this as an issue before, but I like the solution enough that I'll end up using it myself.