# Timeout is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, setinterval

if I create an interval it returns to me an object of type `Timeout`:

```js
> pid = setInterval(() => console.log('x'), 100000)
```

> Timeout {   _idleTimeout: 100000,   _idlePrev: [TimersList],
>   _idleNext: [TimersList],   _idleStart: 9405,   _onTimeout: [Function],   _timerArgs: undefined,   _repeat: 100000,   _destroyed: false,   domain: [Domain],   [Symbol(refed)]: true,   [Symbol(asyncId)]: 73,
>   [Symbol(triggerId)]: 5 }

however, I can't seem to verify that (I'm writing tests):

```js
> pid instanceof Timeout
```

> ReferenceError: Timeout is not defined

I've looked around and found this:
[How can I detect if an object is an interval/timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36434900/how-can-i-detect-if-an-object-is-an-interval-timeout) which alludes to the fact that I should be able to reference it, but in NodeJs that doesn't seem to work

what is the canonical way to determine whether an object represents a Timeout?

Comment: Did you try running `const Timeout = setTimeout(function(){}, 0).constructor;` first, as it says in that answer? That way, it will be defined

Comment: gosh.  I've got egg on my face

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I detect if an object is an interval/timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36434900/how-can-i-detect-if-an-object-is-an-interval-timeout)

Comment: I can't close it by myself... maybe I should just delete the question