# My JS timer clock is not stopping when clicked twice on start button

Tags: javascript, html, date, setinterval

I have a simple HTML stopwatch logic where I can start and stop the clock with the button click. By clicking on the `start` button, one can start the timer (shows current time) and update every second. One can stop it by clicking `stop` button. But if one clicks on `start` button twice, there is nothing I can do to stop the timer. Below is my code:

```js
var hour = document.getElementById("hoursOut");
  var minute = document.getElementById("minsOut");
  var second = document.getElementById("secsOut");
  var btnStart = document.getElementById("btnStart");
  var btnStop = document.getElementById("btnStop");

  var waitTimer;

  function displayTime() {
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var currentHour = currentTime.getHours();
    var currentMinute = currentTime.getMinutes();
    var currentSeconds = currentTime.getSeconds();

    hour.innerHTML = twoDigit(currentHour) + ":";
    minute.innerHTML = twoDigit(currentMinute) + ":";
    second.innerHTML = twoDigit(currentSeconds);
  }

  function twoDigit(digit) {
    if (digit < 10) {
      digit = "0" + digit;
    }
    return digit;
  }

function startClock() {
    waitTimer = setInterval(displayTime, 1000);
  }

  function stopClock() {
    clearInterval(waitTimer);
  }

  btnStart.onclick = startClock;
  btnStop.onclick = stopClock;
```

```html
    <h1>JavaScript Clock</h1>

    <div id="calendarBox">
      <!-- OUTPUT TIME VALUES -->
      <p class="timeDisplay">
        <span id="hoursOut">00:</span>
        <span id="minsOut">00:</span>
        <span id="secsOut">00</span>
      </p>

      <!-- BUTTON SET -->
      <input id="btnStart" type="button" value="START" />
      <input id="btnStop" type="button" value="STOP" />
    </div>
```

I have checked some answers in stackoverflow but most solutions uses a `for-loop` from 0 to 1000 until it finds the interval id and stop all of them using loop. I am confident there should be an elegant solution than that.

```
// some stackoverflow suggested answer
    for (var i = 1; i < 99999; i++)
         window.clearInterval(i);
```

Comment: You need to clear the interval (if it exists) before setting it again

Comment: Simply add some flag, eg isStarted=false and change it on first start. Then add a if(isStarted) to your start function

Comment: Calling `setInterval` returns an integer interval id you can pass to `clearInterval(id)` later. `setInterval(displayTime, 1000);` is fundamentally inaccurate. See [JavaScript countdown timer with on key press to reset the timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51665217/javascript-countdown-timer-with-on-key-press-to-reset-the-timer/51665348#51665348).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you double click you start a new setInterval().  So you now have two set intervals running.  Only problem is you can't access the first one cause you named the second one the same name.  Check if waitTimer exists and if it does stop it.  see code:

UPDATE:  actually you don't even need an if statement.  just call stopClock() before you set waitTimer  -- code snippet adjusted

```js
var hour = document.getElementById("hoursOut");
  var minute = document.getElementById("minsOut");
  var second = document.getElementById("secsOut");
  var btnStart = document.getElementById("btnStart");
  var btnStop = document.getElementById("btnStop");

  var waitTimer;

  function displayTime() {
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var currentHour = currentTime.getHours();
    var currentMinute = currentTime.getMinutes();
    var currentSeconds = currentTime.getSeconds();

    hour.innerHTML = twoDigit(currentHour) + ":";
    minute.innerHTML = twoDigit(currentMinute) + ":";
    second.innerHTML = twoDigit(currentSeconds);
  }

  function twoDigit(digit) {
    if (digit < 10) {
      digit = "0" + digit;
    }
    return digit;
  }

function startClock() {
    stopClock();
    waitTimer = setInterval(displayTime, 1000);
  }

  function stopClock() {
    clearInterval(waitTimer);
  }

  btnStart.onclick = startClock;
  btnStop.onclick = stopClock;
```

```html
<h1>JavaScript Clock</h1>

    <div id="calendarBox">
      <!-- OUTPUT TIME VALUES -->
      <p class="timeDisplay">
        <span id="hoursOut">00:</span>
        <span id="minsOut">00:</span>
        <span id="secsOut">00</span>
      </p>

      <!-- BUTTON SET -->
      <input id="btnStart" type="button" value="START" />
      <input id="btnStop" type="button" value="STOP" />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to prevent the problem before it happens. You can place a check on the running timer ([Is there a way to check if a var is using setInterval()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679141/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-var-is-using-setinterval)).

In this case you could just have a global timer variable `var timer = false` the with add a check to the `start` function. Then the `stop` function will set the timer variable back to false.

```
     function startClock() {
        if(!timer){
          timer = true
          waitTimer = setInterval(displayTime, 1000);
        }
        else return
      }
    
      function stopClock() {
        clearInterval(waitTimer);
        timer = false
      }
```